React, Node.js, jwt Login process. I can't stay the state with accessToken
I'm using accessToken and refreshToken to login process. I made up my mind to store accessToken in React useState and refreshToken in Cookie by using httpOnly. accessToken is saved in state. refreshToken is saved Cookie. As I login page i can acces next page but when I press F5, I go back to login page. It's doing well to get accessToken but I have no idea why the website force me to go to login site. Here's my code
const ProtectedRoute = ({ element, allowedRoles }) => {
  const { accessToken } = useContext(RoleContext);

  let role = "";

  if (accessToken !== "") {
    const decodedPayLoad = jwtDecode(accessToken);
    role = decodedPayLoad.role;
  }

  if (!accessToken) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" replace />;
  }

  if (!allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return element;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

// Create an Axios instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000", // Adjust the baseURL according to your backend API
  withCredentials: true,
});

// Axios request interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const accessToken = RoleContext.accessToken;
    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);


// Axios response interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const {
      config,
      response: { status },
    } = error;
    const originalRequest = config;

    if (status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const { setAccessToken } = RoleContext;
      const navigate = useNavigate();

      try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.post("/auth/token");
        const newToken = res.data.accessToken;
        setAccessToken(newToken);
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
        originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
      } catch (err) {
        navigate("/auth/login");
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;

const ProtectedRoute = ({ element, allowedRoles }) => {
  const { accessToken } = useContext(RoleContext);

  let role = "";

  if (accessToken !== "") {
    const decodedPayLoad = jwtDecode(accessToken);
    role = decodedPayLoad.role;
  }

  if (!accessToken) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" replace />;
  }

  if (!allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return element;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

const AppRoutes = () => {


  const { accessToken } = useContext(RoleContext);
  let role = "";

  if (accessToken !== "") {
    const decodedPayLoad = jwtDecode(accessToken);
    role = decodedPayLoad.role;
  }

  const isAuthenticated = !!accessToken;

  console.log(isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <Navigate
            to={
              isAuthenticated
                ? role === "superadmin"
                  ? "/superadmin/index"
                  : role === "admin"
                  ? "/admin/index"
                  : "/user/index"
                : "/auth/login"
            }
            replace
          />
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/superadmin/*"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute
            element={<SuperAdminLayout />}
            allowedRoles={["superadmin"]}
          />
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/admin/*"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute
            element={<AdminLayout />}
            allowedRoles={["superadmin", "admin"]}
          />
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="/user/*"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute
            element={<UserLayout />}
            allowedRoles={["superadmin", "admin", "user"]}
          />
        }
      />
      <Route path="/auth/*" element={<AuthLayout />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

root.render(
  <RoleProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRoutes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </RoleProvider>
);



If you're looking to persist data across page loads, refreshes, or even between different tabs in a React application, relying solely on component state or context isn't sufficient.
To maintain data such as an access token effectively, consider storing it in a cookie or local storage. This ensures the data remains accessible even when the user navigates away or refreshes the page.
You can create a custom React hook to retrieve the token from the cookie whenever it's needed. This approach allows you to easily access and use the token across your application.

Thank you Santhosh ! I understood what's you were saying. I need to use LocalStorage or Cookie to maintain data. I'm worried that what if my data which is stored localstorage is stolen by someone. so I made refreshToken. Is it possible use refreshToken instead of LocalStorage and Cookie??

what kind of information is present in access token and refresh token ?
It is a good practice to not store any sensitive information in refresh or access tokens. You can have user id and expiry set in the token to keep it simple and secure.
